# Evaluating a table of functions at a point in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to know if it is possible to evaluate a table of functions at a point in *mathematica*.

Right now I am given a table of 10 functions and would like to evaluate them at x = 0.

I tried this :

```
Evaluate[myTable, {x, 0}]
```

And it does not evaluate anything, it just gives this output:

```
Sequence[ {term1, term2, term3, term4, term5, term6, term7, term8, term9, term10}, {x,0}]
```

Replacing term1 ... term10 with the actual terms.

How would I be able to do this?

Thanks,
Bucco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through[{f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,10}[0]]

Comment: How would I do this with the table? Could I iterate through the tables contents in any way? Thanks for the quick answer!